# Are there any map plugins that can show online users?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any good map generator otherwise than Dynmap with better zooming and see online players?

I found [this one](http://minecraft404.net/map/#/137/64/-89/-2/mcmapLighting) through google but can't find which mod is it.

Any help?

Comment: Why is dynmap outdated? If we knew we could suggest an alternative that solved it's issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [DynMap](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/misc-dynmap-v0-20-realtime-minecraft-maps-1000.489/) and it's quite adequate. =)

Comment: Seems I'm stuck with it :S